# typescript + angular2 pass class from a string value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
class SimpleComponent {

}


var string = 'SimpleComponent';

bootstrapComponents.push(string); // This should be 'SimpleComponent' class and not a string value.
```

How can I pass class object from a string value in typescript?

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve? Perhaps there is a better way to implement this.

Comment: Where did you use object?

Comment: @RomanC I'm using object in angular bootstrap method... so it will bootstrap thous objects and I'm passing dynamic values in array, which will load thous component, which then will be bootstrap.

Comment: @NateMay added description on previous comment

Comment: @Basit yes, this sounds like the angular modular import export system. Angular will only load modules that a required, i.e. the router directs to the component. This was by design and abstracts away the need to manage component bootstrapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the class name as a key

```
var classPointer={'SimpleComponent':SimpleComponent};

 bootstrapComponents.push(classPointer[string]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the modular concept of angular2 isn't to store classes in arrays or objects and push them around, it is to export classes and import them elsewhere. In stead, segment you application into modules and load them via the router. Unused modules and their respective components will only load once they are needed, unless otherwise specified via lazyload.

Comment: 1. router is giving issues currently with non-spa app, 2. my solution would load more then one component and freely without in app-root (works better for non-spa).